# How to separate minute tens and ones digit

Tags: pebble-sdk, cloudpebble, pebble-js

I currently have this code written:

```
var timeText = new UI.TimeText({
position: new Vector2(0, 25),
size: new Vector2(144, 30),
text: "%H:%M",
font: 'bitham-42-bold',
color: 'black',
textAlign: 'center'
});
```

This would output, if the time was 12:34, 12:34.  I am trying to achieve an output of 1 2 3 4.  How should I go about extracting and separating the ones and tens place of the hour and minute?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to store the time into its own variable first, then separate it out from there.

I would try something like this:

```
var timeString = "%H%M";
```

Then, you have two options, this is how you can do it with a `for` loop:

```
var timeT = "";
for(int i = 0; i < timeString.length; i++){
    if(i > 0) 
        timeT+= " ";

    timeT += timeString.CharAt(i);
}

var timeText = new UI.TimeText({
    position: new Vector2(0, 25),
    size: new Vector2(144, 30),
    text: timeT,
    font: 'bitham-42-bold',
    color: 'black',
    textAlign: 'center'
});
```

Or, you can do it the explicit way:

```
var timeText = new UI.TimeText({
    position: new Vector2(0, 25),
    size: new Vector2(144, 30),
    text: timeString.CharAt(0) + " " + timeString.CharAt(1) + " " + timeString.CharAt(2) + " " + timeString.CharAt(3);
    font: 'bitham-42-bold',
    color: 'black',
    textAlign: 'center'
});
```

As a warning, I have not tested the run of this code, it may require some small tweaks to get it working but it should be comprehensive of what you are needing to format the text the way you wanted.